# CQ5 Rich Text Editor HtmlRules DocType node being ignored

Tags: aem, rich-text-editor

The widget API suggests that you can change the default wrapping tag for the rich text editor content via the DocType object on the HtmlRules object under a rich text editor:

defaultEditBlock : String
The default edit block type to use; defaults to "p" Added in CQ 5.4.

I need to change this so that I can include the content of a rich text editor field within a p tag which has a particular class (you cannot put one p tag inside another so the automatic wrapping breaks out of my predefined p tag).

Unfortunatly it would seem that this node is being ignored.

What do I need to do to remove the p tags or if not that then change them to something that would go inside a p tag?

The following is the xml for the rich text editor, the rtePlugins node seems to work correctly but not the htmlRules node.

```
<introText
     jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
     allowBlank="{Boolean}false"
     fieldLabel="Intro text"
     name="./introText"
     xtype="richtext">
     <htmlRules jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
         <docType jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                  defaultEditBlock="span">
         </docType>
  </htmlRules>
  <rtePlugins jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <edit jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
              features="[cut,copy,paste-default,paste-plaintext]"/>
        <format jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
               features="[]"/>
        <justify jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                 features="[]"/>
        <lists jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
               features="[]"/>
    </rtePlugins>
</introText>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet? I'm seeing the same thing that the defaultEditBlock is getting ignored.

Comment: I do see this post on adobe forum https://forums.adobe.com/message/4910201 not sure if you have tried this out and also not sure if it will work in all browsers. The way I see to achieve this is by overriding the getValue of rich text which will return the value for span instead of <p>. I have tried overriding for one of our reqirement where in we don't want any wrapping i.e. no <p> tags when we get value from rich text. Override will definitely work and its easy to achieve. Let me know if you need more details on how to override richtext.