# Disable auto-adding of <p> tag

Tags: html, aem, rich-text-editor

I'm trying to remove auto-adding of `<p>` tag in CQ5(Version 5.6.0.20130125). I've tried to add these properties to the [text component](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.RichText) I'm using but with no effect.([source](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4908946#4908946))

```
removeSingleParagraphContainer   true
singeParagraphContainerReplacement    (empty string)
```

I've also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798280/cq5-rich-text-editor-htmlrules-doctype-node-being-ignored). Again, no effect.

Is it possible to disable auto-adding of `<p>` tag?

Thanks for any ideas

**EDIT** I've tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17968732/2022162) but CQ still adds `<p>` tags to my code. For example, I have this HTML code

```
<strong>Headquarters:</strong>
<p>MY - COMPANY a.s.<br>
Random Street 77<br>
Random City</p>
```

and after I submit it, the code changes to

```
<p><strong>Headquarters:</strong></p>
<p>MY - COMPANY a.s.<br>
Random Street 77<br>
Random City</p>
```

my RTE looks like this

```
<text jcr:primaryType="cq:widget"
      hideLabel="{Boolean}true"
      name="./text"
      xtype="richtext">
  <htmlRules jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
      <docType jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
          ...
      </docType>
      <blockHandling
          jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
          removeSingleParagraphContainer="{Boolean}true"/>
  </htmlRules>
</text>
```

**EDIT2** this is what my hierarchy looks like
[image]

Answer (score 12):

You can keep the RTE from surrounding your text with `<p>` tags by setting the `removeSingleParagraphContainer` property to `true` as long as you only create one paragraph.

With Chrome on Mac OS X (at least), holding <kbd>shift</kbd> while pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> inserts line breaks instead of paragraph breaks so you can still create text with multiple lines. Since you said in [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946117/strong-tag-getting-replaced-to-b-tag-in-cq5) that you're using the `misctools` plugin, you can use the source edit view to peek at the markup as you go.

Finally, to set the `removeSingleParagraphContainer` property, you'll need to create another child called `blockHandling` under your `htmlRules` node in your dialog. You don't need to mess with `singeParagraphContainerReplacement` property, but if you did, you would set it on the same node:

```xml
<rtePlugins jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
    ...
</rtePlugins>
<htmlRules jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
    <docType jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        ...
    </docType>
    <blockHandling
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        removeSingleParagraphContainer="{Boolean}true"/>
</htmlRules>
```

**Edit regarding your edit:** using the source edit feature of the `misctools` plugin and pasting this exact text saves and loads without `p` tags for me in Chrome on Mac OS X:

```html
<strong>Headquarters:</strong><br>
MY - COMPANY a.s.<br>
Random Street 77<br>
Random City
```

Are you sure your dialog.xml deployed properly? Maybe double-check that your component's dialog hierarchy looks how you'd expect it to in CRXDE Lite:

[image: CRXDE Lite text nodes]

Comment: I've tried it, but it doesn't seem to work... Check edit of my question

Comment: @Jakolcz - I guess I wasn't very clear with the "as long as you only create one paragraph" condition. You can't have any paragraph tags in your html unless there's only one set and it wraps the entire string. What happens if you take out the `p` tags and put a `br` tag after the closing `strong` tag?

Comment: The `<p>` tags are added to beginning and to the end of my text.

Comment: @Jakolcz - I added some additional context. If you just enter a single word does it get `p` tags added? Are you using IE as your browser?

Comment: I'm using Chrome on Windows Server and when I add the HTML you've posted here, the CQ still adds `p` tags. And I'm using CRX to edit everything, so the hierarchy looks like yours. I'm adding my screen in a second

Comment: Yes, when I add just single character, the CQ also adds the `p` tags. I've also added screen to my question.

Comment: Your dialog looks correct, so I'm not sure what the issue is. I guess your javascript could be different -- I'm using the 20130129 build of 5.6.0, and technically the documentation says the `removeSingleParagraphContainer` property should be a property on the docType node (see API docs [here](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.rte.HtmlRules.DocType)). That didn't work for me, but maybe you should try removing the blockHandling node and setting the property on the docType node instead.

Comment: Stuck on the same problem. I actually just want to change my default <p> to a <div>, that's all. In the Widget API (5.6.1), under HTMLRules Doctype, I've found a parameter defaultEditBlock : String which doesn't seem to do anything. Obviously either the API is out of date or something else is wrong with the node setup. I didn't know about the blockHandling node that was mentioned. Tried it, still no go. I can't have a single paragraph limitation for my producers.

Comment: Work's well to me. It only add <p> when I use `enter`, if I use `shift` + `enter`, the html stills clean! Very good.
Hey man, how can you discovery this!? I cant find nothing about this in adobe documentation...

Comment: One note - after adding removeSingleParagraphContainer="{Boolean}true" into my node, I had to edit the field and re-save it before the <p> tag would go away.

Answer (score 2):

The property `removeSingleParagraphContainer` should be added in node with `xtype` is `richtext`.
Example:

```
<text jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
   hideLabel="{Boolean}true"
   name="./text"
   height="{Long}520"
   removeSingleParagraphContainer="{Boolean}true"
   xtype="richtext">
```

CRXDE Lite: [configuration in crxde lite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MS141.png)

**Note:** And this configuration is only used for single paragraph.

Refer: [more info about removeSingleParagraphContainer](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.RichText)

Answer (score 1):

Try using @context='html' in your code. This lets you set the context of the text as html so even if there are tags in your dialog value, they will be rendered as equivalent html and not as tag on the page. 
eg : 
{properties.something @context='html'}

Answer (score 0):

For Touch UI, you can also create a custom paraformat option in the AEM Touch UI, cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog/richtext, and then using Java Backend, Sling Model, to text-transform the output, so that your Sightly HTL can render the output Html as expected. For the full tutorial, you can find it here.

https://sourcedcode.com/blog/aem/aem-richtext-remove-p-tag-removesingleparagraphcontainer-for-touch-ui

Answer (score -2):

Try using ***@context='unsafe'*** in your code. You should be able to get rid of the unnecessary HTML tags, worked for me