# cq5 richtext adding <p> tag on each line

Tags: extjs, aem, richtext

In CQ5 : xtype "richtext" allows the author to enter data in a rich text editor.

Whenever I hit a enter to enter text in new line, the following code is generated for each line of text.

```
<p><b>Australia/New Zealand</b></p>
<p><b>+61 00 1234 34567</b></p>
<p><b>Japan</b></p>
<p><b>+81 00 1234 34567</b></p>
<p>Additional offices in this region</p>
```

I do see the output as in the above picture.
What I really wanted is below

[image: Actual Output]

[image: Expecting Output]

I tried setting "removeSingleParagraphContainer" to Boolean true. But it doesn't show any affect.

It seems I am missing something. When I hit enter button / returned, the cursor should go to immediate next line, rather than two lines.

I appreciate any help on this.

Things I tried :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Using enter always starts a paragraph in rich text editor. I guess you need to use shift + enter to add a single line break.

Comment: @rakhi4110 SHIFT+ENTER goes to immediate next line, but I wanted the cursor to go to immediate next line on hitting enter button. I wish I could use stackoverflow rich text editor, which goes to immediate next line when I hit enter.

Comment: Checkout following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965276/disable-auto-adding-of-p-tag

Answer (score 0):

In richtext editor of AEM, if you would like to break line, you should use `SHIFT + ENTER`. It will generate a `<br/>` tag.

`ENTER` will break your text in new paragraph. It generates a `<p>` tag.